# using +1 as position to cycle through images and words in a list?

Tags: java, android, image, list

So I am very new to programming and java and can't get this to work.
I am trying to make a quiz  app where if you type in the correct answer new images show up and the correct answer changes. I stored the answers and images in lists and now I want it to cycle to the next item in the list if the answer is correct. But I seem to be doing something wrong.
Sorry if this is a dumb question and thanks in advance for any help!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button sbm_btn;
    EditText edittext;
    Log mytag;
    ImageView imgv1;
    ImageView imgv2;
    ImageView imgv3;
    ImageView imgv4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        onButtonClick();
       }

        public void onButtonClick () {

            imgv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imgv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imgv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            imgv4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

            sbm_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbm_btn);
            edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerfield);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            final ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();   // My list of answers
            answers.add("james bond");
            answers.add("queen elisabeth");

            final int[] view1 = {                                  // my lists of images, the third is placeholder for testing
                    R.drawable.car,
                    R.drawable.crown,
                    R.drawable.pistol};
            final int[] view2 = {
                    R.drawable.london,
                    R.drawable.oldwoman,
                    R.drawable.pistol};
            final int[] view3 = {
                    R.drawable.smoking,
                    R.drawable.dress,
                    R.drawable.pistol};
            final int[] view4 = {
                    R.drawable.pistol,
                    R.drawable.island,
                    R.drawable.pistol};



            sbm_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int number = 0;
                        if
                                ((edittext.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(answers.get(number)))) {
                                    number++;           // Why doesnt this work?

                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Well Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();

                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    imgv1.setImageResource(view1[+1]);      // this seems to work swappping pictures once and after that does nothing.
                                    imgv2.setImageResource(view2[+1]);
                                    imgv3.setImageResource(view3[+1]);
                                    imgv4.setImageResource(view4[+1]);

                                }
                            }, 1300);

                        } else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "WRONG!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();

                        }


                    }
                }
        );


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't initialize number to 0 within your click (that will reset that number to zero each time you click). You need to do it before you click (inside in the class, not inside the method). Also, your java syntax is super convoluted because you don't know it well enough. I'd suggest you practice with http://codingbat.com/java

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a very logical explanation why it didnt work.
I will have a look at improving my syntax as well, I haven't followed a proper course or anything, I'm just trying to teach myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try puting int number =0; into field erea at the top of your class.